# Analytical Solution to a simple l1 norm problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Can we solve this simple optimization problem analytically?

$ \min_{w}\dfrac{1}{2}\left(w-c\right)^{2}+\lambda\left|w\right| $

where c is a scalar and w is the scalar optimization variable.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  It would help us answer it if you shared the context of the problem.  It would also help if you shared what you've tried so far.

Comment: @vadim123, thanks. I came across this problem in this paper "Structured Feature Selection and Task Relationship Inference for Multi-Task Learning". Eqn (17), (18). The solution was given in terms of the optimization variables. Which did not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(w) = \frac{1}{2}(c-w)^2+\lambda|w|$. Since $|\cdot|$ is not differentiable at $0$, some care must be taken when locating the minimizers. In particular, it is not necessarily the case that the minimizer of $f$ occurs at the minimizers of $w \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(c-w)^2 \pm \lambda w$ separately.

It is clear that $f(w) \uparrow \infty$ as $|w|\to \infty$, hence a minimizer exists.

If we take $c=1, \lambda = 2$ we see that the minimizer occurs at $w=0$, which is not a minimizer of the separate functions. It occurs because, under the appropriate circumstances (the slopes of the individual functions must be opposite in sign), we can have a minimizer when $\frac{1}{2}(c-w)^2+\lambda w = \frac{1}{2}(c-w)^2 -\lambda w$, which reduces to $w=0$.

[image]

More formally, we note that $f$ is locally Lipschitz, so we can compute the Clark generalized gradient at $w$ as
$\partial f(w) = \begin{cases} \{w-c+ \lambda \operatorname{sgn} w, & w \neq 0
\\ \{-c\}+ [-|\lambda|, |\lambda|], & w = 0 \end{cases}$.
At a minimum, we will have $0 \in \partial f(w)$.

If we take $w>0$, then $0 \in \partial f(w)$ implies $w =c-\lambda$
(which means we must have $c > \lambda$). Similarly, if $w<0$, we get $w =c+\lambda$ (which means we must have $c< -\lambda$).

If $w=0$, then $0 \in \partial f(0)$ implies $0 = -c + \xi$, where $|\xi| \le |\lambda|$, (which implies $|c| \le |\lambda|$).

For this it is clear that $\min_w f(w) = \min (f(c-\lambda), f(0), f(c+\lambda))$.

If $\lambda\ge 0$, then the above shows that $\min_w f(w) = \begin{cases}
f(c-\lambda), & c > \lambda \\
f(0), & |c| \le |\lambda| \\
f(c+\lambda), & c < -\lambda  \end{cases}$

Answer (score 2):

Set $f(w)=\frac{1}{2}(w-c)^2+\lambda |w|$, equal to $\frac{1}{2}(w-c)^2\pm\lambda w$.  We find $f'(w)=w-c\pm \lambda$.  Setting this to zero gives $c\pm \lambda$ as the only critical values of $f$.  As $w$ gets large, $f(w)$ grows without bound, so the minimum is going to be at one of the two critical values.  At those values, we have $f(c+\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\lambda|c+\lambda|$, and $f(c-\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\lambda|c-\lambda|$.  Which one is minimal depends on whether $c,\lambda$ are the same sign or different signs.

Also need to compare with $f(0)=\frac{c^2}{2}$, $f$ is nondifferentiable there.

Comment: Under certain conditions, this approach 'misses' a minimizer at $w=0$, where $f$ is not differentiable.